# Add attribute to disable parallel execution for some features in Specflow + Nunit

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow

Hi i am using specflow + nunit ,

I have made all the features to run parallel by adding the following in assembly level.

```
[assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
[assembly: LevelOfParallelism(5)]
```

But now I have some features which should not run parallel and I want to exclude those tests. I know that `[NonParallelizable]` or `[Parallelizable(ParallelScope.None)]` are used in *Nunit* projects to exclude them from parallel execution. But for *specflow* where do I specify these. Since the `.cs` file is autogenerated in *specfow*. how do i add these attributes?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this one?

Comment: Sadly there is no direct feature in SpecFlow for this.

But there is a workaround:

We generate the code-behind classes as a partial class. So you can create a file with a partial class and add there the [NonParallizable] attribute.

Comment: I actually found it's possible to create a generator plugin that can add attributes to the generated nunit test classes. I ended up creating a runtime plugin that tries to sync access for some of the tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly there is no direct feature in SpecFlow for this.

But there is a workaround:

We generate the code-behind classes as a partial class. So you can create a file with a partial class and add there the [NonParallizable] attribute.

It looks like this:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
namespace ParallelExecution.Features
{
[NonParallelizable]
public partial class CalculatorFeature
{

}
}
```